# Separate data encryption

Tags: encryption-symmetric

I store some sensitive data. Data is divded into parts and I want to have separate accees to each part. Let's assume that I have 1000 files. I want to encrypt each file by the same symetric encryption algorithm. 
I guess that breaking a key is easier when hacker has got 1000 cryptogram than he has only one cryptogram, so I think that I should use separate key for each file. 
My question is following:

**Should I use separate key for each file?**

If I should, there is problem with storing 1000 keys. So I want to have one secret key and use some my own algorithm to calculate separate key for each file from secret key. Is it good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider passive adversary and use CPA-strong cipher (like AES), it is sufficient to use only one key for all files. Supposing adversary knows the cipher you use, and even knows plaintexts, he cannot reconstruct the key with non-negligible probability. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51960/is-it-possible-to-guess-an-aes-key-from-a-series-of-messages-encrypted-with-that) is more detailed answer.

If you consider also active adversary (which can replace ciphertexts) you should use Authenticated Encryption. But as I understand this is not your case.

> So I want to have one secret key and use some my own algorithm to calculate separate key for each file from secret key. Is it good idea?

In general, developing your own algorithm or scheme is bad idea. You can easily make some unseen mistake in algorithm or implementation and you data will be vulnerable. It is better to use well-known algorithms and implementations peer-reviewed by lots of people and proved to be secure.